# Golang Server Sent Events Per User

Tags: go

I've been working with Go for some time but never done SSE before. I'm having an issue, can someone PLEASE provide with a working example of server sent events that will only send to a specific user(connection).

I'm using a gorilla - sessions to authenticate and I would like to use UserID to separate connections.

Or should I use 5 second polling via Ajax?

Many thanks

Here is what i found and tried:

1. https://gist.github.com/ismasan/3fb75381cd2deb6bfa9c it doenst send to an individual user and the go func wont stop if the connection is closed
2. https://github.com/striversity/gotr/blob/master/010-server-sent-event-part-2/main.go this is kind of what i need but it doesnt track once the connection is removed. So now, once you close and open the browser in private window it's not working at all. Also, as above, the go routine keeps going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a "broker" to distribute messages to connected users:

```
type Broker struct {
    // users is a map where the key is the user id
    // and the value is a slice of channels to connections
    // for that user id
    users map[string][]chan []byte

    // actions is a channel of functions to call
    // in the broker's goroutine. The broker executes
    // everything in that single goroutine to avoid
    // data races.
    actions chan func()
}

// run executes in a goroutine. It simply gets and 
// calls functions.
func (b *Broker) run() {
    for a := range b.actions {
        a()
    }
}

func newBroker() *Broker {
    b := &Broker{
        users:   make(map[string][]chan []byte),
        actions: make(chan func()),
    }
    go b.run()
    return b
}

// addUserChan adds a channel for user with given id.
func (b *Broker) addUserChan(id string, ch chan []byte) {
    b.actions <- func() {
        b.users[id] = append(b.users[id], ch)
    }
}

// removeUserchan removes a channel for a user with the given id.
func (b *Broker) removeUserChan(id string, ch chan []byte) {
    // The broker may be trying to send to 
    // ch, but nothing is receiving. Pump ch
    // to prevent broker from getting stuck.
    go func() { for range ch {} }()

    b.actions <- func() {
        chs := b.users[id]
        i := 0
        for _, c := range chs {
            if c != ch {
                chs[i] = c
                i = i + 1
            }
        }
        if i == 0 {
            delete(b.users, id)
        } else {
            b.users[id] = chs[:i]
        }
        // Close channel to break loop at beginning
        // of removeUserChan.
        // This must be done in broker goroutine
        // to ensure that broker does not send to
        // closed goroutine.
        close(ch)
    }
}

// sendToUser sends a message to all channels for the given user id.
func (b *Broker) sendToUser(id string, data []byte) {
    b.actions <- func() {
        for _, ch := range b.users[id] {
            ch <- data
        }
    }
}
```

Declare a variable with the broker at package-level:

```
 var broker = newBroker()
```

Write the SSE endpoint using the broker:

```
func sseEndpoint(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // I assume that user id is in query string for this example,
    // You should use your authentication code to get the id.
    id := r.FormValue("id")

    // Do the usual SSE setup.
    flusher := w.(http.Flusher)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/event-stream")
    w.Header().Set("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
    w.Header().Set("Connection", "keep-alive")

    // Create channel to receive messages for this connection.  
    // Register that channel with the broker.
    // On return from the function, remove the channel
    // from the broker.
    ch := make(chan []byte)
    broker.addUserChan(id, ch)
    defer broker.removeUserChan(id, ch)
    for {
        select {
        case <-r.Context().Done():
            // User closed the connection. We are out of here.
            return
        case m := <-ch:
            // We got a message. Do the usual SSE stuff.
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "data: %s\n\n", m)
            flusher.Flush()
        }
    }
}
```

Add code to your application to call Broker.sendToUser.